# fullcalendar title range is wrong in new version for the week view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, title

I am using latest version of the fullcalendar for my project. 3.1.0
I noticed that what I am trying to accomplish here actually used to work but then got broken in version 2.*.* of some kind.
Please see these fiddles for comparison.

Old version:

[Fiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/jsguru30/jRFYE/818/)

New Version:

[Fiddle that doesn't work](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jsguru30/8auggxcm/61/)

Both fiddles above use this type of code to setup the title:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },       
    editable: true,
    weekends:false,
```

Notice that in the working one, title adjusts correctly date wise, where none working one still lists saturday and sunday range
Could you please tell me what the changes are and why it got broken?
I think they were working on the fix, but is there anything I can do right now to fix the code?

Comment: If you are curious, here is the official ticket for the bug you describe: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: moment(),
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  defaultView: 'basicWeek',
  weekends: false,
  eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
    var firstDate = moment($('th.fc-day-header:first').data("date"));
    var lastDate = moment($('th.fc-day-header:last').data("date"));
    if (firstDate.month() == lastDate.month()) {
      $('.fc-center').find('h2').html(firstDate.format('MMM') + ' ' + firstDate.format('D') + ' - ' + lastDate.format('D') + ', ' + firstDate.format('YYYY'));
    } else {
    //logic to show title for dates with different months / years
      $('.fc-center').find('h2').html('');
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dLakt4ya/)

Comment: Thank you, I updated your fiddle to fit what I need. I need title to be between next and prev button and look something like 1/9/2017 - 1/13/2017  format wise.. I did notice an issue though.
[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jsguru30/dLakt4ya/5/)
if you navigate to the weeks that have month change so if same week has 1/31 and 2/1 etc, it doesn't show title between the buttons

Comment: Hi @coder. In case when start date and end date are in different month/year, you have to implement it by your own. I only gave you something to work on ;) There are actually 3 formats needed: **Dec 24 – 30, 2017** or 
**Apr 30 – May 6, 2017** or 
**Dec 31, 2017 – Jan 6, 2018**

Comment: No problem, I got it to work on my end the way I need it. So that's great.
I was curious to see if you might know the answer to my last post:
[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616271/fullcalendar-event-click-vs-link-inside-the-event)