# fullcalendar event click vs link inside the event

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar

I have a question. Maybe this is not possible but I was hoping for clarification. Fullcalendar right now has it so if there is a url inside the event, the whole event is clickable and just takes you to that particular url.
In my case I need to have a link inside the event that has to be clickable.
See [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jsguru30/dLakt4ya/6/)

Please let me know if there is a way to disable the event click itself but only keep the click of the link available. I know that there is a way to disable an event like this:

```
 eventClick: function(event) {
        return false;
}
```

However, this will disable everything even the link inside the event. Eventually all of the events will be pulled via ajax or some other way from DB to populate the calendar. So keep in mind that I will need to provide a URL in some way for the event to pick it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the example from fullcalendar [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'My Event',
    start: '2017-01-13',
    url: 'http://google.com/'
  }],
  eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
      //if you want to open url in the same tab
      location.href = "https://example.com";
      //if you want to open url in another window / tab, use the commented code below
      //window.open(event.url);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

I don't know how do you render the link in your events, but this should do what you need.

Comment: Hey, see what I am doing here:
[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jsguru30/dLakt4ya/11/)
I think I almost got it. In my case when i click on the event, nothing happens... i click on link it goes to google.com
However, one thing that puzzles me and I can't seem to reproduce in fiddle but in my application when I click on X mark to remove the event, it removes the event but also goes to google.com and I don't know why.
In fiddle it just gives an error "Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." trying to open url but it shouldn't

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/s3dc9w73/ In one of my projects I added some icons to event body and detected click on them this way. Maybe it will work in your case too.

Comment: OK that worked but cause an issue with one of the prior tickets you answered.
Can you please take a look  at this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618941/fullcalendar-event-deletion-doesnt-calculate-total-by-the-header-correctly)

Comment: Hi! I will be able to help you with deletion and calculating total times first thing tomorrow morning. Gotta go now. Are you polish by any chance? ;)

Comment: Hey was going to send you the chat but apparently I am too low on points rather than bombarding this comment section. It worked great! You are awesome at this. For now, I don't think I need drag and drop feature, however, If i will need it, may I reach out back to you unless I figure out how to adjust these totals? As drag and drop is not calculating them right. I don't need it just yet. But thanks again!

Comment: drop me a line at krzysztof@mobilestudio.pl I will have a look at dropping during the weekend